# kerberos kinit gives java.lang.NullPointerException on Windows server 12

Tags: java, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos, kerberos-delegation, mit-kerberos

When I run kinit command on windows server 2012 it gives null pointer error. please give me any solution.

```
D:\Junk_Folder>kinit user
Password for user@DOMAIN.COM:
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCReqBody.asn1Encode(KDCReqBody.java:242)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCReq.asn1Encode(KDCReq.java:202)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReq.encoding(KrbAsReq.java:148)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:319)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:364)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.<init>(Kinit.java:221)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.main(Kinit.java:113)
```

Comment: Does _user_ actually exist in _DOMAIN.COM_?  Do you have a krb5.ini properly configured for Kerberos client name resolution?

Comment: its an encryption issue  and i resolved it .Thanks you @T-Heron :)

Comment: Can you indicate how you solved it?

Comment: Actually its windows encryption issue. In my krb5.ini file ,i wrote  `default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac-nt` but `rc4-hmac-nt` is not working in windows so i tried `rc4-hmac` and it is working fine.